# Ionic spinner while Angularfire Firestore is loading

Tags: ionic-framework, angularfire, google-cloud-firestore

In an Ionic project i am using the code below to load a document collection from Firestore with the AngularFirestore wrappers.

Now that the content starts loading when the view was initialized i'm experiencing a delay by about 4-8 seconds until the firestore fetched data renders in my list-view, which is very very bad for the overall userexperience.

with the code below i'm able to show a loading spinner when the content starts loading bit i need it to stop showing the loader.

I have no clue how to trigger that event? Any help would be appreciated

thank you very much

```
    import { City } from './../../model/City';
    import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { NavController, IonicPage, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
    import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

    @IonicPage()
    @Component({
      selector: 'page-home',
      templateUrl: 'home.html'
    })
    export class HomePage implements AfterViewInit {
      citiesRef: AngularFirestoreCollection<City>
      cities: Observable<City[]>;

       loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
        content: 'Loading Regions...'
      });

constructor(private loadingCtrl: LoadingController, private afs: AngularFirestore, public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.loading.present().then(()=>{
      this.citiesRef = this.afs.collection<City>('regions', ref => ref.orderBy('name'));
      this.cities = this.citiesRef.valueChanges();
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, what I did was I subscribe to the this.cities. It worked in my case. The idea is it will fire loading.dismiss() once it is able to subscribe. Hope that helps

```js
let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
    content: 'Please wait...'
  });

  loading.present();

    this.citiesRef=this.afs.collection('cities');
    this.cities=this.citiesRef.valueChanges();
    this.cities.subscribe(_=>{
      loading.dismiss();
    })
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, it worked for me :-) In both ways, with Firestore and RealtimeDB